# "On rational surfaces with a pencil of elliptic curves"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I'm looking for a translation or an  English source that treats the topics of Dolgachev's paper ["On rational surfaces with a pencil of elliptic curves"](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/a2f2bf1b5eff00ec4b0f693ffb83ff50/im2872.pdf). I can only find a Russian version. I am particularly interested in the following: 
Let $F$ be a cubic curve and $p_1,...,p_9$ points on $F$. These $9$ points are the basepoints of a pencil of degree 3n if and only if $n (p_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus p_9)=0$ with respect to the group law of $F$.

It is mentioned [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Halphen_pencil) that the statement about $n (p_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus p_9)$ can be given meaning in case of singular F. Is there an English source for that?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't even understand enough for that. Here is the [link](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/a2f2bf1b5eff00ec4b0f693ffb83ff50/im2872.pdf) to the paper. My guess is that it is on page 1087, theorem 2. Thank you very much for your effort. (well this comment was the response to a comment that obviously doesn't exist anymore :))

Comment: Have you looked at Cantat and Dolgachev, "[Rational surfaces with a large group of automorphisms](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-2012-00732-2)," §2.2?

Comment: They consider the irreducible case. Looking at the Russian paper there seems to be an extension to the reducible case, which would be interesting.